# Git removed files after a push and pull that were mistakenly included in gitignore, can they be restored?

Tags: git

I initialised a repo and linked it to a remote host that was empty but for gitignore and readme. I mistakenly put a wildcard in my .gitignore that caused files I want to be ignored, I subsequently pushed and pulled. The local and remote repos now do not include the files I want and the remote never did. Can those files be recovered?

Comment: Did you delete the files in the project?

Comment: Not purposefully but I believe git has removed them after I did a pull and they were in the ignore list

Comment: Ah, nope. Git won't mess with them unless they had been tracked. If they had been ignored, they won't show up in status and git won't mess with them (there are situations where it _might_ mess with them, but certainly not your described scenario).

Answer (score -1):

After changing your `.gitignore` file. Where you originally commited your commit from the local machine and then pushed to remote, you can add the files in, if you have them available.

A commit would only contain the files, which have been added for tracking, to be committed.

Comment: the files are not in my local repo or on the remote master

Comment: If you had the files elsewhere on the local machine, then you can add them to your or, after changing your `.gitignore` file. If you do not have the files then, you may try to run a file recovery software on the local machine to hopefully retrieve the files and then check them properly, and then commit them.